# Does it matter which ASP.NET Project type I use for a super-simple site?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013, single-page-application

I'm going to create a super-simple, one-page, site. It will have text  and images and links on it, that's all.

No code, either C# or jQuery or anything else - just some HTML (and minimal CSS).

I created mockups of the site (page) using VS 2013 by selecting New > Project > Web Site > ASP.NET and then each of the following, in turn:

```
Empty Page
SPA
Web Forms
```

For the first two, I added an HTML page and copied my HTML and CSS and ran it. It works fine.

For the last option (Web Forms), the difference was that there was already a page (Default.aspx). I replaced the existing HTML in there with mine (and my CSS). It also works fine.

I plan on publishing it to/with/as an Azure web site. I assume I can do this with any of these project types.

The Web Forms adds a bunch of stuff I don't need or use, so I imagine one of the other two would be my best bet. Is there any reason why I would select one project type over the others for a simple page like this?

Comment: Why are you creating a web application when all you want is static html?

Comment: Can I publish static HTML? If so, how?

Comment: Usually, you just ftp it to your site.  Or you would use an HTML authoring tool, like Expression or Dreamweaver... In a pinch, there are a number of great open source alternatives.  Try http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/ (note, I have no affiliation with coffee cup, I just know they're reputable)

Comment: But that's the point - it isn't a site yet. I need it to be a public site people can navigate to. I'm just trying to find the easiest way. I think option #1 is probably the best - it carries the least baggage, and it's easy to publish to azurewebsites.net

Comment: You're not making sense.  What do you mean it's not a site yet?  A site is just a collection of web pages.  You only need one really, the homepage.

Comment: I think he means he doesn't have it hosted anywhere yet, and he's hoping that it'll be easier to host on Azure by using Visual Studio.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: You've got it. IMO, it is "just a collection of web pages" or, in this case, A web page, until it's accessible to the public at large.

Comment: I'm "hosting" my page right now on jsfiddle; I'm thinking about using DropBox as a permanent "host" for it, by just making the .html a public file - that should work for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a static site and you know what HTML/CSS you want to use, your best bet with Visual Studio is to use the Empty Page template.